# Нужна программа с абсолютным позиционированием

Tags: windows, кроссплатформенность, c++, linux

Дана задача, сделать кроссплатформерную программу (допустим содержащую текст "Hello World", но в абсолютном позиционировании). Тоесть мне нужна программа, которая в OC Windows она отобразится ровно, а допустим в OC Linux, текст куда-нибудь съедет. Как это можно реализовать? Поверхностно знаю С++, можно даже сказать что вообще его не знаю.

Comment: Замечу, что если Вы хотите программу, которая абсолютно (pixel-perfect) одинаково выглядит на всех платформах, то Вы получите программу, которая выглядит на всех платформах одинаково мерзко и ненативно. Увы, но горькая правда.

А так — можно. Хотя если нужно, чтобы текст не «ехал», то только картинкой. Растризаторы шрифтов на всех системах разные, в итоге один и тот же текст (характерно для маленьких размеров шрифта), отрисованный в разных ОС, рискует иметь разные пиксельные размеры.

Comment: вы не совсем правы, есть возможность рисовать все самому но это гемор еще тот :)

Comment: Рисование самому = одинаково мерзко и ненативно на всех платформах. Ну или близко к нативному, но это сколько же придется работы делать (анимации виджетов, шорткаты, интеграция с десктопом, ...), для того, чтобы сделать то, что уже написано и предоставлено операционкой/widget toolkit'ом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что раз это исследовательская работа по теме "Кроссплатформенное программирование" , то для начала нужно сделать маленький обзор, рассказывающий что же это такое за программирование и какие инструменты (тулкиты) позволяют им заниматься. Далее следует написать пару тестовых приложений на разных тулкитах с использованием разных библиотек и проанализировать их поведение в разных тестовых средах (Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, разные варианты Linux), причем обязательно попробовать различные настройки сред: разные размеры экранов и разные размеры экранных шрифтов (имеется в виду стили оформления, изменяемые в настройка самой операционной системы). А далее просто собственными глазами посмотреть разницу и сделать выводы почему есть эта разница и как от нее избавиться.

Ответы с вариантами условной компиляции плохие, т.к. они не соответствуют цели работы.

Answer (score 2):

```
int offset=5;

#ifdef WIN32 // Windows code here
    offset=0;
#else // UNIX code here
    offset=2;
#endif

#include <string.h>

....

string s;

for(int i=0;i<offset;++i) s.push_back(" ");//вставляет offset пробелов в строку s
printf("%sHello world",s.c_str());
```

[Подробнее о макросах, определяющих операционную систему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063110/get-the-current-operating-system-during-runtime-in-c)

Comment: мне нужно добится естественного сьезда текста в программе. Неужели нет такой проблемы, что в разной ОС отображается всё по разному?

Comment: Вообще не очень понятно, что такое "съезд"? Кривое позиционирование бывает от кривых рук кодера, а от ОС никак не зависит. Если говорить о GUI, то кросплатформенные библиотеки работают везде одинаково (Qt, wxWidgets etc. А если неодинаково, то это баг в библиотеке и его нужно чинить. Если же программист настолько недалёк, что под каждую ОС пишет код отдельно, то см. выше про кривые руки.

А консоль - она везде консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Считывайте разрешение экрана. и пересчитывайте в относительных единицах.
Тогда не зависимо от операционной системы , текст будет находится физически на одном месте.

Comment: ему нужно определить на какой ОС запускается программа

Comment: А зачем? не зависимо от ОС если пересчитывать координаты вывода в зависимости от разрешения экрана, физически текст останется на одном месте.
темболее форматы файлов для разных ОС разные, так что проблеммы определения ОС нет, ну не сможет вот просто так взять и запустиь ехе под Линухом, и линуховый софт под Виндой не запуститься без шаманства.

Comment: если заюзать java, то проблему с кросплатформенностью можно решить, к сказанному об координатах - [Operating System Information][1]. только окошко прийдется отрисовывать, но там просто.


  [1]: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/OSInformation.shtml

Comment: ну ХешТэег стоит C++

Comment: @savro, у него в тексте есть фраза: "Поверхностно знаю С++, можно даже сказать что вообще его не знаю.", поэтому на теги особо внимания обращать не стоит :)

Comment: Ну с++ он хоть поверхностно встречал , а Java , вообще будет лес дремучий.

Comment: сейчас много видео уроков по java. не так-уж и сложно разобраться, если есть желание. хотя никто не говорил что бинарник может быть один и тот-же, может код быть один и тот-же...

Comment: Тут главное чтобы было желание, разобраться можно и в ASM .
Да и не понятна формулировка мне нужна программа и втоже время не знание языков, толи лаба, толи человек сам не знает что хочет.

Comment: У меня исследовательская работа по теме Кроссплатформерное Программирование. Я выбрал проблему позиционирования интерфейса программы в разных ОС. Как можно создать такую проблему?

Comment: Проблему вы уже создали, когда тему выбрали

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич, так Вам нужна идея программы (простой, a'la HelloWord), вывод которой на экран в виндоусе и линуксе будет различаться, а после некоторых изменений кода она станет выводить одно и то же?

Answer (score 0):

Нужна программа с разными реакциями на операционные системы?
Используй #ifdef WIN32 для определения в какой операционной системе компилируется программа.

Например:

```
#ifdef WIN32
printf("Hello Windows!\r\n");
#else
printf("Hello Linux!\r\n");
#endif
```

Я порой пишу кросс платформенные программы, вот таким образом определяя под какую ось она собирается и что нужно изменить, чтобы программы выдавали одинаковые данные.

Comment: Не имея возможности добавить комментарий к следующему ответу добавлю сюда.
В принципе я уже провел работу по изучению, как писать программы под разные платформы. Я не различаю различные версии Windows, под XP и 7 один и тот же код работает одинаково. С линуксами такая же картина. Остается написать кроссплатформенные функции, которые будут вызывать нужные функции системы в зависимости от платформы. Вначале это создает проблемы, потом такая программа совершенно легко компилируется под андроид.